# Why is this "while let" loop an infinite loop?

Tags: rust, while-loop, infinite-loop

```
#[test]
fn test_looping() {
    let index: usize = 2;
    while let Some(index) = index.checked_sub(1) {
        println!("{}", index);
    }
}
```

Why does this create an infinite loop? I'd expect `index` to be overwritten by the `while let` expression. Instead, I have to add a couple extra lines to get it to mutate `index`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let` declares a new binding, shadowing the previous one. It doesn't modify the existing variable. That `index` isn't initially declared as `let mut index` is a sign that it's not being mutated.

To fix it, write:

```
#[test]
fn test_looping() {
    let mut index: usize = 2;
    while let Some(i) = index.checked_sub(1) {
        index = i;
        println!("{}", index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I did end up writing something like this, but was just curious what "rule" I was breaking!